# Save figure with two plots, specified size and resolution (scientific paper)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to submit a figure with two very similar violin plots on it. The requirements of the journal are:

- Labels must be sharp and clearly legible (including exponential numbers around figure axis) NOT blurry, fuzzy, faded or broken.
- Please do not use various fonts in the labels (preferred fonts Arial and Times New Roman NOT both). The labels should be of the same font and size throughout the figures.
- The font size of the labels must be 8-10 point when figures are saved at the correct size (8 or 17 cm at 300 dpi/inch).
- The first letter of each phrase must be capitalized [e.g., 'Overall survival (months)' not 'Overall Survival (Months)', not 'OVERALL SURVIVAL (MONTHS)' and not 'overall survival (months)].
- Zero should be placed before decimals. e.g., 0.08 and NOT .08.
- Full stop should be used to indicate the decimal. e.g., 0.08 and NOT 0,08.
- Empty white space around a figure should not be included when calculating image size; images should be cropped (cut) as close to the outside edges of the figure as possible.

Here what I've done. So the first violinplot is:

```
x=['No','Yes']
l=[0.0,1.0]
g = sns.violinplot(x="Relapse", y="Age_at_diagnosis", data=df, aspect=2)
g.set(xlabel='Relapse', ylabel='Age at diagnosis')
g.set_xticks(l)
g.set_xticklabels(x)
```

And the second one is very similar, though the column differs:

```
x=['No','Yes']
l=[0.0,1.0]
g = sns.violinplot(x="Death", y="Age_at_diagnosis", data=df, aspect=2)
g.set(xlabel='Death', ylabel='Age at diagnosis')
g.set_xticks(l)
g.set_xticklabels(x)
```

**Would you** advise me on how to plot them one below another on one figure, with dpi=300 and width=8cm?

I thought of adding something like in the beginning:

```
# Edit the font, font size, and axes width
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Arial'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10
plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 1
```

but then get stuck with the size, dpi and placement of those two plots.

Comment: I dont get your point 8cm ~ 3.14961 inches, which has been specified in your code..

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) for a `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` states that `figsize` must be provided as a `(width, height)` tuple in inches. That specific keyword argument does not accept centimetre units. However, for ease of usage and for your own readability, you can easily assign a variable for width and height in centimetres, then convert it when you pass it to the `figsize` keyword argument.

```py
width_cm = 8.0
height_cm = 5.99
# ...
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(0.39 * width_cm, 0.39 * height_cm))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily plot multiple plots within a figure with plt.subplots()

There are many detailed examples here:
[Creating multiple subplots using plt.subplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it returns two blank boxes and following error:TypeError: missing a required argument: 'dataset'